# What are the different Vaishnava interpretations on the nature of Lord Vishnu's physical form?

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, philosophy

I understand that Lord Vishnu's body is *aprakrita*, composed of *sat-chit-ananda*, but is it understood to have a **physical** reality?  i.e. four arms, two legs, one head, two eyes, five fingered hands, ie, a basic humanoid form that predates the creation of humans.

How does it contrast with the *Advaita* understanding of *nirguna brahman*?

Comment: Related : [What are the views of Vishishtadvaita on Nirguna Brahman?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14713/277)

Comment: Our Supreme Self with minimal presence of pure mind is Saguna Brahma Who has apkrita forms.When the mind dies, the seer seeing and seen merges. this is what i read.